# I'm creating an edge table, how to prevent duplicating edges

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

The query is like so:

```
       CREATE TABLE Edge_Table AS
       SELECT a.*gid,nextval('ty') AS edge_gid, 
       ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(a.geom, getcentroids(a.gid)),4326) AS geom_line 
       FROM Points_table a;
```

where my getcentroids Function returns 8 nearest points to each point creating an edge with each one of them, the problem arises with duplicates as same edge is created from 1->2 and 2->1, how do I optimise this query itself as large data has to be processed, could index or UNIQUE constraint help?

Comment: a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column and a `DISTINCT` in your selection query will  do the job.